# Why Google Search Console is not picking up the bio back-link in my blog?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, backlinks

I have been writing some blogs, in order to create some back-links for my website.

One of the website that I used is [c-sharpcorner.com](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com)

I have my profile page: [my-profile-page-on-c-sharpcorner](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/members/hooman-bahreini)

And I have written the following three blogs (on *c-sharpcorner*):

1. [working-with-files-and-folders-in-s3-using-aws-sdk-for-net](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/working-with-files-and-folders-in-s3-using-aws-sdk-for-net)
2. [submitting-a-form-to-different-action-methods-in-asp-net-mvc](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/submitting-a-form-to-different-action-methods-in-asp-net-mvc)
3. [how-to-define-custom-password-validation-rules-in-asp-net-mvc](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-define-custom-password-validation-rules-in-asp-net-mvc)

All of these 3 blogs, contain a back-link to my website, at the bottom of the page:

[image]

But when I open Google Search Console, only 1 link from *c-sharpcorner* domain is pointing to my website:

[image]

Why is Google Search Console not considering the back-links from my blogs? One of these blogs have been viewed 20k times and appears really high in google search result... and it has been around for 6 months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google does not see your Bio or the Comments. Do a Rich Results Test on one of the pages. View the rendered html and you won't find the text for your Bio.

Dig into the page loading issues and you will find several scripts blocked from Google due to robots.txt commands. One script is to add the Bio and one to add the comments. As Google will not run those scripts, their content is not added, and Google does not see it.

Maybe a deliberate move by the site owner to deter people from posting just to get links.

Comment: I checked **Rich Results Test** and couldn't find the bio... How can I find the commands in robots.txt? Does it mean that `c-sharpcorner` is blocking the Google from seeing the bio section? I am confused, does Google use a different version of the page for indexing, because the bio section is displayed?

Comment: It's the robots.txt line: Disallow: /WebServices/
So it looks like its a broad disallow that happens to block the bio and comment requests.
Google honours the robots.txt command and does not see those sections. You are not a robot so can make the requests and see the content.

Comment: Thanks, may i ask where do find the robots.txt file?

Comment: The robots.txt file is always in the root of the domain property that it influences. e.g. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/robots.txt

Answer (score 3):

According to Google employee Pierre Far, the link report of Google Search Console is not guaranteed to be complete:

> Keep in mind also that Webmaster Tools show a sample of links, but isn't guaranteed to show 100%. So some links may exist to either URL that aren't necessarily displayed in Webmaster Tools.
>
> https://www.seroundtable.com/google-link-tool-sample-data-13636.html

Furthermore, Google employee John Mueller says that ["if our systems don't even show them there, then they're pretty irrelevant overall"](https://www.reddit.com/r/bigseo/comments/b6koze/if_search_console_doesnt_list_an_indexed_link/).

So according to Google employees, the system is working as intended, and has determined that your links are not relevant enough to show in Search Console. Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: Thanks for this... so does it mean that because the back-link is quite small and close to the bottom of the page, it's not any good?

Comment: @HoomanBahreini That's possible, but I would say it's more likely that Google picked its one link up from your blog article that got so much attention, and decided to ignore the other two links because it didn't deem the containing pages to be important enough.

Comment: Thanks... I can check the the link in Google Search Console, it is pointing to my-profile-page... non of the 3 blogs are picked up (or mentioned) in GSC.